# Jquery if statement not working with data attribute

Tags: jquery

When filter button is clicked I would like it to hide all the li where the data attribute 
hasrelated=0

html

```
<li data-mostsaved="0" data-hasrelated="0" data-mostplayed="2">img</li>
```

JQ

```
$( ".has-related" ).click(function() {
        if ($("li").data('hasrelated') == '0') {
            $("li").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `$("li").data` is going to fetch the FIRST `<li>` found in the document, grab its data attribute, and test that. You need to test EVERY `<li>` that has a hasrelated attribute in turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".has-related").click(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('hasrelated') == '0') {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to check *where the data attribute hasrelated=0*, as in:

```
$('li[data-hasrelated=0]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dxh7upe3/)**

I've written this using `$.each` function by jQuery:

```
$("a_button").click(function(){
  $("li").each(function(){

      var a = $(this).data("hasrelated");
      if(a == 0){
       $(this).toggle();   
      }

  });

});
```